# ImageMagick - convert an image's white colors to another, keeping transparency and excluding black

Tags: imagemagick

I have a large set of images. The default is a white color that should be modified to a specific hex code, with any black that exists in the image left alone (as it denotes a symbol). The white is usually part-transparent, and that should be kept if it is. Any completely transparent areas should be kept transparent.

I'm batch processing using Powershell -- `$ColorHex` refers to a hex value in an array. The generated file should match the color produced.

[Original Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCijg.png)

[Green (#009900) - colorize 70%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk1tv.png)

`magick ".\FFFFFF.png" -fuzz 5% -fill "#$ColorHex" -opaque "#FFFFFF" -colorize 70% "$ColorHex.png"`

[Green (#009900) - fuzz 75% -opaque](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odHRN.png)

`magick convert ".\FFFFFF.png" -fuzz 75% -fill "#$ColorHex" -opaque "#FFFFFF" "$ColorHex.png"`

Generally this is what I want, but doesn't preserve the partial transparency of the white when converting to green AND is rough at the black edges (would prefer it to be aliased).

I have a ton of images I want to process in this fashion and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you only want pure (opaque) white changed, do not include -fuzz. If you want partially transparent white changed, then what is your ColorHex value?  Did you include transparency? For Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want in Imagemagick 7. Here I make an in-memory copy of the image. I then turn alpha off and process all pure white. Then I extract the alpha channel from the in-memory copy and put it back onto the resulting green image.

Input:

[image]

Unix syntax:

```
magick nCijg.png +write mpr:img \
-alpha off -fill "#009900" -opaque "#FFFFFF" \
\( mpr:img -alpha extract \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
result.png
```

Windows syntax:

```
magick nCijg.png +write mpr:img ^
-alpha off -fill "#009900" -opaque "#FFFFFF" ^
( mpr:img -alpha extract ) ^
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite ^
result.png
```

Result:

[image]

You can include some fuzz if you want to include non-white to fill some small holes in the white.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I amped the fuzz up & for icons without borders was able to colorize them (using -colorize 100%). Thank you so much.